# Lift Archetype Basic JPA 2.9.1 won't compile

Tags: scala, maven, lift

I'm new to Scala, Lift, and Maven, and I'm running into a problem. I created a new JPA project based on the Lift-JPA archetype, as follows:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=net.liftweb -DarchetypeVersion=2.4-M4 -DarchetypeArtifactId=lift-archetype-jpa-basic_2.9.1 -DarchetypeRepository=http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases -DremoteRepositories=http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases -DgroupId=ltest -DartifactId=lift_test -Dversion=1.0
```

Then I tried to compile it using mvn compile. I got the following error (I think this is the relevant part):

```
[INFO] Compiling 9 source files to /lift_test/spa/target/classes at 1329115047063
[ERROR] /lift_test/spa/src/main/scala/ltest/model/CurrencyUserType.scala:39: error: private value cz escapes its defining scope as part of type java.lang.Class[_ <: CurrencyUserType.this.cz.Currency]
[INFO]   override def returnedClass = cz.CurrencyUnit.getClass
[INFO]                ^
[ERROR] /lift_test/spa/src/main/scala/ltest/model/Enumv.scala:43: error: value map is not a member of ltest.model.Enumv with Enumeration
[INFO]   def getNameDescriptionList =  this.map(v => (v.toString, getDescriptionOrName(v) ) ).toList
[INFO]                                      ^
[ERROR] /lift_test/spa/src/main/scala/ltest/model/EnumvType.scala:49: error: value valueOf is not a member of Enumeration with ltest.model.Enumv
[INFO]       return et.valueOf(value).getOrElse(null)
```

(Paths anonymized--it's not in my root directory)

I'm really not sure what's wrong. These are all classes from the archetype--I haven't added anything to the project. I have a feeling I'm doing something very basic wrong, or I have something configured wrong, but I don't know what. Only thing I can think of is that I'm using Maven 3, and I think these archetypes were designed for Maven 2.

Comment: Try maven 2, if that also fails, try asking in the mailing list at http://groups.google.com/group/liftweb?pli=1

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have an unsupported archetypeVersion try 2.4-M5 or don't specify it and let maven find it.